# Why android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" not working with device

Tags: android

I am using `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`

to split the `Menu's` .it is working fine with emulator `4.03`

but not with real device `4.03`.It is samsung tablet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`splitActionBarWhenNarrow`, as the word suggests, only works on small (narrow) devices like phone - splitting controls between top and bottom. It will not split when run on wide devices like tablets.

Reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html, search for `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`.